# Parallel Matrix Multiply with OpenMP on different ways

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, parallel-processing, openmp

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <string.h>


void matrix_multiply(int n, int m, int p, int **A, int **B, int **C) {
  int i,j,k,v;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < p; j++) {
      v = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < m; k++) {
        v += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
      }
      C[i][j] = v;
    }
  }
}

void show_matrix(int **M, int n, int m) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      printf("%d\t", M[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void prepare_matrix_data(int **M, int n, int m) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
          M[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
      }
  }
}

int **create_matrix(int n, int m) {
  int **M = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      M[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
  }

  return M;
}

void free_matrix(int **M, int n, int m) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      free(M[i]);
  }
  free(M);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int csvMode = 0;
  int n = 1;
  int m = 1;
  int p = 1;
  int maxIteratios = 1000;

  if (argc > 1) {
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "csv") == 0) {
      csvMode = 1;
    }
  }

  if (argc == 5) {
    n = atoi(argv[2]);
    m = atoi(argv[3]);
    p = atoi(argv[4]);
    maxIteratios = n+1;
  }

  if(csvMode == 1) {
    printf("n,m,p,time[s]\n");
  }

  for ( ; n < maxIteratios; n++, m++, p++) {
    int **A;
    int **B;
    int **C;
    double start, end;

    A = create_matrix(n, m);
    prepare_matrix_data(A, n, m);

    B = create_matrix(m, p);
    prepare_matrix_data(B, m, p);

    C = create_matrix(n, p);

    start = omp_get_wtime();
    matrix_multiply(n, m, p, A, B, C);
    end = omp_get_wtime();

    if(csvMode == 1) {
      printf("%d,%d,%d,%f\n",n, m, p, end-start);
    } else {
      printf("Czas wykonania dla parametrow n=%d, m=%d, p=%d wynosi: %f sekund\n",
      n, m, p, end-start);

      printf("Macierz C (A * B):\n");
      show_matrix(C, n, p);
    }

    free_matrix(A, n, m);
    free_matrix(B, m, p);
    free_matrix(C, n, p);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Hi, trying to parallel this matrix multiply with OpenMP. As task I need check all posibility so if in method 'matrix_multiply', first for is Z, 2. is X, 3. is Y, then I should check for all like: [z], [x], [y], [z,x], [z,y], [x,y], [z,x,y] (for in squares mean that he will be parallel).

I tried somethink like that

```
void matrix_multiply(int n, int m, int p, int **A, int **B, int **C) {
  int i,j,k,v;
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(8) reduction(+: v) shared(A, B, C)
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < p; j++) {
      v = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < m; k++) {
        v += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
      }
      C[i][j] = v;
    }
  }
}
```

But for n,m,p = 100 I got Segmentation fault (core dumped). Which from upper possibilities are  valid to test, and how do it? I tried all loops and all time got randomly 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'.

___edited
Now I tried

```
void matrix_multiply(int n, int m, int p, int **A, int **B, int **C) {
  int i,j,k,v;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < p; j++) {
      v = 0;
      #pragma omp parallel for shared(A, B, C, v) schedule(static)
      for (k = 0; k < m; k++) {
        v += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
      }
      C[i][j] = v;
    }
  }
}
```

but got bad and random result each time.

__edit
Now this:

```
      #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: v) schedule(static)
```

for 'for Y' and looks like working but what with another?

Comment: You have a major problem with loop variables. Start by making them all local to the loop header. Variables should always be as local as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look on your 3 different Approaches

1. You are creating a simple parallel region instead of a parallel loop, so the loop code will be executed entirely by the 8 threads in the parallel region, so we have duplicated work and data race. In addition, you are declaring a reduction on `v`, but this is a local variable and reducting It do not have meaning to the global scope. Also you até declaring only a subset of your variables as shared, when your probably want to declare ALL variables that you will use.
2. Now you have a parallel for, but your `v` is shared without any care for data race conditions: every thread Will update It at the same, so it is expected that at some point some garbage will be stored. Also, as you are creating a parallel region on the innermost loop, you can expect a lot of overhead from the OpenMp runtime due to excessive parallel region creation and destruction
3. I'm not sure about what do you mean by 'for Y', but if you are talking about the second loop, then it Works because you are correctly parallelizing the loop. You are still using a useless reduction as on the first example, but It have no impact on the correctness of the result. Also, as you ommited any clause about scope of variables, the compiler may have choose the best for you (although It may still be flaky as `k` is not private)

The better solution (without modifying the rest of code) IMHO is to put the pragma in the outermost loop with all variables with the correct scope restriction

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) num_threads(8) shared(A, B, C, n, m, p) private(i, j, k, v)
```